# jQuery typeof with OR condition

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery so I want to check variable $test is undefine/empty so my condition is,

```
var $test = '';

1. 
if (typeof($test == 'undefined' || $test == '')) {  
   console.log('Variable is empty');  
}
else  
{   console.log('variable is not empty');  
}

2. 
if (typeof($test) == 'undefined' || $test == ' ')) {  
   console.log('Variable is empty');  
}
else  
{  console.log('variable is not empty');  
}
```

Which condition is valid first one or second one. If the second one then why?

Comment: This is not a question specific to jQuery, it's a general JavaScript question. Please consider changing the tags and title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Neither example you gave is correct:

1. Your first example put parentheses around both comparisons and this causes them to be treated as a single argument to `typeof`.
2. Your second example used `typeof` correctly but then compared to a
   single space (`' '`) instead of the empty string (`''`).

Additionally, you should be using the strict equality operator (`===`) instead of the loose equality operator (`==`) for your comparisons.

Combine the two methods (and note that `typeof` does not require parentheses):

```js
var $test = '';

if (typeof $test === 'undefined' || $test === '') {
  console.log('Variable is empty');
} else {
  console.log('variable is not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof($test) == 'undefined' || typeof($test) == '') {
```

is valid because

In first case it resolves to

```
if (typeof(true/false)) {
```

Which is not a valid condition check you want. You want the second one.